# Редактирование .htaccess для DLE CMS, Редирект 301

Tags: redirect, .htaccess, cms, dle

День добрый, есть сайт на DLE 9.0, как правильно отредактировать htaccess лежащий в корне сайта для для того чтобы срабатывали следующие редиреты

```
с http://www.example.com на http://example.com
с http://www.example.com/index.php на http://example.com
с http://www.example.com/indeh.html на http://example.com
```

Сейчас шапка оригинального htaccess выглядит так

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Редиректы
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?cstart=$1 [L]
```

ниже я добавил

```
# редирект custom 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/index.html$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/index.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

но почему то ничего работать не хочет, правильно ли я понимаю что нужно убать

`RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?cstart=$1 [L]`

выше, чтобы работали  мои ридиректы или это можно как то объеденить!?

Спасибо